# What is allowed on the test set?

Tags: dataset, experiment-design, train

This question considers the set-up of a data set, not learning on an existing data set. The data set we are setting up is comprised of two parts: train and test.

The set as a whole (say, S) is a collection of samples drawn from some greater theoretical distribution (say, U), and to make the set more fun we are thinking of adding extra descriptions to accompany each sample. I suppose this will be S', and similarly there is a distribution U'.

The descriptions --you may think of them as features-- are quite particular (this may be an issue to start with): we look at pairs of samples, and we take note of what makes the one different from the other. Although it is a comparison, we disallow the description to reflect attributes from the "other", so they are valid descriptions of the one sample in its own right. The other is just presented to help with this.

Fact: for any algorithm cracking at our data set, we want the performance on the test set to be representative of its performance on U'.

Here are a few questions:

- Can we do this? (this has to be asked)
- Should descriptions be added before or after dividing into train and test?
- If we decide after (this is the main question), are we allowed to consider pairs both drawn from the test set? Note that the descriptions are simply added so they don't replace anything.

Now, my friend's argument is that you can't consider test-test pairs, because that would bias the evaluation to particularities in the test data, away from U'.

Funnily, my argument is that you should, because ignoring the particularities in the test data (which, we agreed, are also present in U') biases your evaluation to the train data.

Actually, my initial case was that you should add descriptions *before* splitting in train and test. But somewhere I lost that argument.